# Glowing/outline effect when particle and object are colliding

Tags: particles, collision

How to do a glow/outline of collision effect when particles (objects with same size in a group) are entering other object?

For example when a small box particle is falling into a plane (will fall through), when a box starts touching the plane the place of collision (essentially a square on the plane, around the box particle) is being rendered?

Edit: Adding more info as requested. I don't want to share my real scene, so I mocked a simplified version of it.

[image: current state]

Desired effect highlighted with purple colour:
[image: desired effect]

Comment: Please clarify your question by placing an image in your question to illustrate your goal.  Show your current work as well as a Blender screen capture.  Please do these two things in all of your future questions as well.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger Added the requested information. Sorry, didn't know it was required.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46360/only-render-particles-on-silhouette-of-model/46395#46395

Comment: If you have enough permission ... you can safely remove your last comment.  22 questioners a day, new to Blender, decrease the answer rate by leaving out information.  This a common occurrence and you have corrected it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Dynamic Paint and Freestyle**

[image]

Dynamic Paint. Contrasting particle paint with a mysterious mesh object in the shape of a number moving on the z-axis.  The mysterious mesh object is not shown to emphasize the Dynamic Paint process and not mesh movement. No Compositing Nodes. Image Above

---

[image]

Dynamic paint. Stopping particles with collision plane to show coincident locations.

[image]

Dynamic paint with Particle System.

[image]

A dynamic paint render. A cyan plane has been colored yellow with fading where the particles have hit the plane.  Image above.  Please click on image to see a larger version in a different browser window. The images were created by dynamic paint feature and then applied as a texture.

[image]

A Blender Render Node system showing a blur node.  Please improve and customize.

[image]
Dynamic Paint Example. Canvas, Brush, Particle System. Please customize to your tastes. Image above.  One panel is pinned to show data from more than one object.  Note that using a particles system with dynamic paint may eliminate some options that the OP might find useful in a future version of Blender.  The particles above seems to be used for location of the paint effect, disregarding size and shape.  The mesh paint effect which is not a particles clearly respect the volume.  Particles can be made in meshes by make real.  Keep aware of physical forces.

[image]

Mysterious Mesh object brush with brush settings for dynamic paint.  Not a particle. Image above.

[image]

[image]

Files created by Dynamic Paint based on particle system typically used as part of a  Blender File render. 2 Images above.  The yellow blobs show where the particle hit the plane.

- Dynamic paint can detect a contact point / intersection or proximity between

  - Particles and a surface
  - Two objects

and color a surface.

- The Blender compositor can use a [blur node] to create a visual blur because it can recognize different objects by object id.  A blur effect can be composed onto the image.
- Freestyle and the compositor.  Freestyle topic can be searched here at BSE.

[image]

Outlining again.

- You may consider fire/smoke as well.

These three bullet points are high level information.  Tutorials exists for these topics on video websites or you may find smaller explanations here at BSE

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/dynamic_paint/index.html

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/freestyle/index.html?highlight=freestyle

Comment: Thank you for directions :). I am quite a beginner (just a hobbyist tinkering with 3D), so I expect it will take me some time to understand all the concepts and their details. Edit: I am sorry, I can't upvote you (not enough reputation) and I don't feel comfortable with accepting the answer until I manage to make it (at least somewhat) working.

Comment: You can always change an answer vote if someone creates a new answer.  Yes Blender like a number of software programs has 1000s of check boxes and entry fields.  I probably learn/relearn something every time I use Blender ... and the brain kicks out less important features of Blender every time.  You will be learning something a year from now as well as today.  Yes this answer has a lot of information to be learned for any Blender user.  Just do not get BASE.  Blender Aggravation Shock and Exasperation.

Comment: Have you found a way to make DP respond to the _shape_ of a particle object instance? I've got the impression its just a spherical calculation.. maybe you have to convert particles to objects?

Answer (score 3):

If you set up, say, physics on real instances instead of particles, you may be able to use Dynamic Paint on its own..

Set the Cube(s) up as a Brush.

[image]

- It paints white (no alpha) into what will be a black canvas
- From Mesh Volume and Proximity, with the Volume Negated
- And a falloff defined by a color ramp, to give more flexibility with later steps

Set a highly subdivided plane up as a Canvas

[image]

- We're painting into vertex colors here. (You could bake the image sequence into a texture instead, if you wanted to work with a less subdivided plane)
- (Drying) and Dissolving are set up to just a couple of frames, so the paint doesn't persist
- We're using the paintmap in this case.. click the '+' to have it set up

Using the paintmap as a mask in a material for the canvas....

[image]

- It's picked up by an 'Attribute' node, and used to select between two materials.
- The paintmap is put through a color ramp to give us control over the width/feathering of the rim.

There is some aliasing next to the cube, due to the resolution of the vertex-color layer- So I covered it up by parenting another, slightly larger, inert cube to the smaller one actually doing the painting.

This is the sort of result...

[image]

There is an edge-case where a cube-face is exactly parallel to the plane .. then the paint fills the entire square for a frame or two. Haven't found a way round that yet.

[image]

Comment: Is _Negate Volume_ necessary here? When I disable it the aliasing issue goes away without negatively impacting the effect. Still looks just like your final animation.

Comment: @BLayer    Ahh.. you might be on to something.. it was there for me, as a (clunky?) way to get rid of unpredictable entire-volume flash-frames which happened when brushes of various shapes were close to entry or exit. Maybe that was _temporal_ aliasing, though ? I should just have upped the sub steps?  I'll go back and check that out.